# Where the heck is mod_login? (Joomla)

Tags: joomla

I'm a Joomla newbie, and I'm trying to set up a site to require login access to certain articles.  Simply setting the article's Access Level to Restricted makes it disappear rather than prompting for a login.  I can't figure out how to make a login page because I can't find any menu items or documentation pertaining to mod_login.

I want to set at least one page to require login access.  Where do I start?

Comment: move to stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mod-login is found:

Extensions -> Module Manager -> "Login Form"

From there you should be able to choose which files/sections that you want to be prompted for the users name and password.